# Java JPA/Hibernate with SQL Server - How to detect when column in db is not mapped by entity model?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Spring webapp using JPA/Hibernate to map entities, and this works fine to do all the normal tasks e.g. CRUD operations.

I am also able to detect when a field in the model is not present in the database (hibernate throws 'Invalid column name').

My issue is that I now have a requirement to **detect and alert the user when there are new columns in the database which are not represented by the model.**

The reason for this is that the application should always enable the user to set/view all fields present in the database, and not transparently ignore an available field with no notification.

Is there a straightforward way to use JPA/Hibernate to either

1. throw an error if there is a new un-mapped column in the DB, or
2. manually check that all columns are accounted for?

If there's no simple method I suppose I could query against the information_schema but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such `hbm2ddl.auto` option, if you are searching for something like that. For example `update` will only check for mapped columns and ignore additional columns - at least it won't drop them.

So you will have to go the hard way and check by hand:

```
SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) ((Session) this.em.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory();

// Find all mapped tables with all mapped columns
final Map<String, Set<String>> tableColumns = new HashMap<>();

for (ClassMetadata metadata : sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata().values()) {
  AbstractEntityPersister persister = (AbstractEntityPersister) metadata;
  Set<String> columns = new HashSet<>();
  tableColumns.put(persister.getTableName(), columns);
  for (String propertyName : persister.getPropertyNames()) {
    for (String propertyColumnName : persister.getPropertyColumnNames(propertyName)) {
      columns.add(propertyColumnName);
    }
  }
}

for (CollectionMetadata metadata : sessionFactory.getAllCollectionMetadata().values()) {
  AbstractCollectionPersister persister = (AbstractCollectionPersister) metadata;
  // ... extract key, index and element columns from persister, similar to AbstractEntityPersister
}

// Compare columns with existing metadata
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().doWork(new Work() {
  public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : tableColumns.entrySet()) {
      String tableName = entry.getKey();
      ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
      try {
        while (rs.next()) {
          String columnName = resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
          if (!entry.getValue().remove(columnName)) {
            log.error("Column not mapped: {}.{}", tableName, columnName));
          }
        }
        if (!entry.getValue().isEmpty()) {
          log.error("Columns not defined: {}.{}", tableName, entry.getValue()));
        }
      } finally {
        rs.close();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! As much as it's not exactly what I was hoping for it's still a great complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this (without querying metadata it is not possible i guess), you can run this as a job for every 'x' amount of time.

```
public void printMetadata() {
    Set<String> dbColumns = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> entityProperties = null;
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().doWork(new Work() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        //**Post** is EntityClass with `@Table` & `@Entity` annotated.               
        ResultSet resultSet =  connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, null,
                    Post.class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Table.class).name(), null);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                dbColumns.add(resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
            }
        }
    });

    ClassMetadata classMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Post.class);
    entityProperties = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(classMetadata.getPropertyNames()));

    if (entityProperties.size() != dbColumns.size()) {
        //Throw Error.
        //Else, you can compare ColumnName with Property using some pattern.
    }
}
```